# Delete custom cell when a button is pressed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView and a UIButton in a View Controller. In tableView I have 2 custom cells. I want to delete the second custom cell when the button is pressed. The problem is that i didn't find how to do this.

Can someone give me a hint in how to delete an entire cell when a button is pressed?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: remove  object from your datasource array and reload index path of tableview

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you for the hint!